# Is there any method to shrink images without crop in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I found many methods in `tf.image` to resize images, but almost all of them are crop or pad or interpolation. Can the methods with interpolation shrink images? I just want to shrink my images without crop.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems you need [tf.image.resize_images](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images)?

```
res = tf.image.resize_images(images, size, method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR, align_corners=False)
```

default resize method is BILINEAR

```
val = np.random.rand(100, 70, 3)
x = tf.constant(val)
y = tf.image.resize_images(x, (30,30))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run(y)  # size (30, 30, 3)
```

Comment: This method processes images with interpolation, I thought it can only enlarge images, so can interpolation shrink images?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but could you please answer the question? [Is the input of `tf.image.resize_images` must have static shape?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096178/is-the-input-of-tf-image-resize-images-must-have-static-shape)

Comment: ummm ok, but I don't think I can help you

Comment: @zhkai Yes, it will, based on new size

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, images are matrices/tensors. In order to shrink an image directly you will have to do some lossy compression. Namely, average or max pooling on individual groups of pixels (or matrix values) and them save them out as pre-processed images for your model. Try looking into the Tensorflow [max-pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool) and [average-pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/avg_pool) functions:

`tf.nn.max_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, data_format='NHWC', name=None)`

`tf.nn.avg_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, data_format='NHWC', name=None)`

Depending on the application, you may just want to "shrink" images using a model that "creates features" such as a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) that then you can use for your model. However, you still have to process your original sized images on every run.

Another advanced approach is to do some sort of decomposition, such as the SVD, to get a lower dimensional representation of your images. However, most methods are linear techniques and might not preserve everything exactly. Another method is to train an **autoencoder** and then save out the lower-dimensional results out to be the pre-processed data.

Hope this helps!