# Is the input of `tf.image.resize_images` must have static shape?

Tags: tensorflow

I run the code below, it raises an `ValueError: 'images' contains no shape`. Therefore I have to add the line behind `#` to set the static shape, but `img_raw` may have different shapes and this line makes the `tf.image.resize_images` out of effect.
I just want to turn images with different shapes to [227,227,3]. How should I do that?

```
def tf_read(file_queue):
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    file_name, content = reader.read(file_queue)
    img_raw = tf.image.decode_image(content,3)
    # img_raw.set_shape([227,227,3])
    img_resized = tf.image.resize_images(img_raw,[227,227])
    img_shape = tf.shape(img_resized)
    return file_name, img_resized,img_shape
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue here actually comes from the fact that `tf.image.decode_image` doesn't return the shape of the image. This was explained in these two GitHub issues: [issue1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8551), [issue2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9356).

The problem comes from the fact that `tf.image.decode_image` also handles `.gif`, which returns a 4D tensor, whereas `.jpg` and `.png` return 3D images. Therefore, the correct shape cannot be returned.

---

The solution is to simply use `tf.image.decode_jpeg` or `tf.image.decode_png` (both work the same and can be used on `.png` **and** `.jpg` images).

```py
def _decode_image(filename):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])

    return image_resized
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `tf.image.resize_images` can handle dynamic shape

```
file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['./dog1.jpg'])
# shape of dog1.jpg is (720, 720)

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
file_name, content = reader.read(file_queue)
img_raw = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, 3) # size (?, ?, 3)  <= dynamic h and w
# img_raw.set_shape([227,227,3])
img_resized = tf.image.resize_images(img_raw, [227, 227])
img_shape = tf.shape(img_resized)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print img_shape.eval() #[227, 227, 3]
```

BTW, I am using `tf v0.12`, and there is no function called `tf.image.decode_image`, but I don't think it is important

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use tensor object as size input for `tf.image.resize_images`.

So, by saying "turn images with different shapes to [227,227,3]", I suppose you don't want to lose their aspect ratio, right? To achieve this, you have to rescale the input image first, then pad the rest with zero.

It should be noted, though, you should consider perform image distortion and standardization before padding it.

```
# Rescale so that one side of image can fit one side of the box size, then padding the rest with zeros.
# target height is 227
# target width is 227
image = a_image_tensor_you_read
shape = tf.shape(image)
img_h = shape[0]
img_w = shape[1]
box_h = tf.convert_to_tensor(target_height)
box_w = tf.convert_to_tensor(target_width)
img_ratio = tf.cast(tf.divide(img_h, img_w), tf.float32)
aim_ratio = tf.convert_to_tensor(box_h / box_w, tf.float32)
aim_h, aim_w = tf.cond(tf.greater(img_ratio, aim_ratio),
                       lambda: (box_h,
                                tf.cast(img_h / box_h * img_w, tf.int32)),
                       lambda: (tf.cast(img_w / box_w * img_h, tf.int32),
                                box_w))
image_resize = tf.image.resize_images(image, tf.cast([aim_h, aim_w], tf.int32), align_corners=True)

# Perform image standardization and distortion
image_standardized_distorted = blablabla

image_padded = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image_standardized_distorted, box_h, box_w)
return image_padded
```