# Can't Load Files with Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use `tf.Dataset` to load input images and label images. Therefore I'm following the Tensorflow Dataset tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets. But I get this error:

`ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.`

I printed some lines:

This is what is in my `input_files`: `['images/kitchen-1687121_1280.jpg', 'images/room-1706801_1280.jpg']`

`input_filename`: `Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`

`image_string`: `Tensor("ReadFile:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`

```
class DatasetImporter():

    def __init__(self, inputs_path, labels_path):
        self.inputs_path = inputs_path
        self.labels_path = labels_path
        self.dataset = None

    def _get_files(self, path):
        return sorted([path+"/"+f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))])

    def _parse_function(self, input_filename, label_filename):
        print(input_filename) # Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
        image_string = tf.read_file(input_filename)
        print(image_string) # Tensor("ReadFile:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
        image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
        image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28]) # *ERROR* in this line 
        # Similar for the label...
        return image_resized, label

    def loadData(self):
        input_files = self._get_files(dsi.inputs_path)
        label_files = self._get_files(dsi.labels_path)
        print(input_files) # ['images/kitchen-1687121_1280.jpg', 'images/room-1706801_1280.jpg']
        self.dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(input_files), tf.constant(label_files)))
        self.dataset = dataset.map(self._parse_function)

dsi = DatasetImporter("images", "labels")
dsi.loadData()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that you use `tf.image.decode_image` instead of `tf.image.decode_jpeg`. The first one doesn't return any shape because of some issues described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8551) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9356).

I've written a more extensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347663/5098368).